How to securely publish a WinUI3 app that references a ResourceDictionary from a WinUI3 library project?
I have a main WinUI3 app and a WinUI3 library project. The library contains common converts and a resource dictionary. Structure:
WinUiLibrary/
├── ResourceDictionary.xaml
└── (Other source files and converters)
WinUiMain/
├── App.xaml
└── (Other source files)
I am referencing the WinUILibrary project from the main app. The App.xaml uses the resource dictionary from the library like this:
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///WinUiLibrary/ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
            <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Other app resources here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

My concern is that after building my project a WinUiLibrary folder appears in the output folder of the main app that contains a ResourceDictionary.xaml and a ResourceDictionary.xbf. So the output contains the raw xaml/xbf files which should not be exposed to users.
Interestingly after explicitly publishing my app the folder is not there in the published output but the app crashes because it could not locate the ResourceDictionary.xaml file.
So what is the recommended way to use resource dictionary and not expose its content to users?

XAMLs embedded in your assembly should not be marked Embedded Resource. Please look at the XAML item's Properties. They are embedded differently: the build transforms them in the generated temporary source code, and then this code is compiled. This way, you never expose the files to the user. The item should not be marked with Copy to Output Directory (neither Copy always nor Copy if newer).

Does the data of your Resource Dictionary defined in a separate assembly work correctly in the different assemblies where it is used? You are not referencing it as a file of a file system, so this is good. If it works correctly, please see my previous comment and check the XAML file Properties.

@SergeyAKryukov The build action of the XAML file is Page, as recommended for XAML files, not embedded resource. And yes, the data in the XAML file can be loaded in other projects.
If you have a simple WinUI library with a ResourceDictionary.xaml and you add this as project reference to an empty desktop WinUI project and include the xaml in the merged dictionaries, it will create this additional folder with xaml/xbf files in the main app's output.
When it is published with dotnet publish, it won't have this folder with raw xaml files, but it will crash with xaml file not found error.

You see, “...but it will crash with XAML file not found error” tells me that you say correct things but still utilize or reference XAML incorrectly. If you did it correctly, but removing a XAML from output causes a failure, it is certainly so (do I understand you correctly, removing file cases the crash?) Such things are resolved by creating the simplest possible solution: only one XAML with only one property, and only two assemblies. If you can reproduce the issue, you could 1) better see the problem, 2) provide all those small files with your question.

Just checking: I can see your scheme Source="ms-appx:// that I did not use. (I use on a regular basis Source="pack://application:... ) But the issue is: how your Source could possibly work without referencing the assembly itself? You need to 1) reference the assembly containing the XAML in question in your project (project reference), 2) reference the same assembly in your Source. Not just the XAML file itself. The XAML file is not at all the file, this is the location used to find the XAML code in the assembly you reference.

So, you may need to look at the usage of the URI schemes like ms-appx:// or pack://.. in the documentation. Pay attention to how the URI should reference the assembly already referenced by your project. Chances are, it can solve your problem.
